# Adding parameter to "Queue New Build" Dialog

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I built a custom build processes template based on the DefaultTemplate.xaml and added a few parameters. They show up fine on the Build definition window but I can not find a way to have them be displayed on the parameters tab of the Queue New Build Dialog.

I am hoping that this is possible, I would rather not need to define a separate build for each variation of parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define that in the Metadata parameter: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx

You can play with the "View the parameter when" option at the bottom

Comment: Link doesn't work, try this: https://web.archive.org/web/20110218214028/http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx