# TFS 2010 Build Pick a configuration at build time

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

How can i configure a build definition to allow me to pick a solution configuration at build time?

I have 3 configurations in my solution: (Local, UAT and Live).

I want people to pick and the configuration they need and the build will do the config transforms, deployment etc. as required. I have the build script I need, just need to know how I can switch upon the configuration.

If I cannot use the actual configurations, a custom property would do, but obviously I need to be able to access it in my build script.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that your Build Defition should contain all three configurations, so that Build shall execute all three of them by default.
Then, you can insert a custom argument in your build process template as an "Configuration Override" with default = empty.
Checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672074/adding-parameter-to-queue-new-build-dialog) Hofman-post you can have your argument part of the 'Queue new Build dialog.
So, when your users queue a new build, they either leave this empty and build executes all configs, or they enter one of the three and only the one selected shall be executed.
There are various ways to implement this in your build process template, in general you might want to intervene in section `For Each Configuration in BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations`:
[image]

and check if your custom argument is empty (so all nodes should execute), or if it is filled with a specific entry (so it should proceed only once). Further handling of a user input that does not comply with any of the available configs should be added, so that build can graciously fail.